# Is there any better way to do name categorisation based on uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I want categorized the free text written name and make a categorical variable after this

1. `Only first`      : Only first letter is capital
2. `Standard usage`  : First letter every words is capital
3. `All capital`     : Every letter is in capital letter
4. `All small`       : Every letter is in lover case
5. `Unidentified`    : Not in any of 4 category above

Here's my data

```
Id   Name
1    Donald trump
2    Barack Obama
3    Hillary ClintoN
4    BILL GATES
5    jeff bezoz
6    Mark Zuckerberg
```

What I want

```
Id   Name                 Category
1    Donald trump         Only first
2    Barack Obama         Standard usage
3    Hillary ClintoN      Unidentified      
4    BILL GATES           All capital
5    jeff bezoz           All small
6    Mark Zuckerberg      Standard usage
```

What I did is

```
df['Uppercase'] = df['Name'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()
df['Lowercase'] = df['Name'].str.findall(r'[a-z]').str.len()
df['WordCount'] = df['Name'].str.count(' ') + 1
```

Then do some logic using `map` function, such us:

```
`df['Lowercase'] = 0` for `All capital`
`df['Uppercase'] = 0` for `All small`
`df['Uppercase'] - df['WordCount'] = 0` for `Standard usage`
`df['Uppercase'] = 1 and `df['WordCount']` for `Only first`
```

If this does't belong to anything it labelled as `Unidentified`

But, `naBih baWazir` will be recorded as `Standard usage` based on standard rule, not `Unidentified`, I think there's any better way to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions [`Series.str.islower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.islower.html)
[`Series.str.isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html)
[`Series.str.istitle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.istitle.html) and for new column [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#test all letters without first for lower and first value for upper
m1 = df['Name'].str[1:].str.islower() & df['Name'].str[0].str.isupper()
m2 = df['Name'].str.istitle()
m3 = df['Name'].str.islower()
m4 = df['Name'].str.isupper()

df['Category'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], 
                           ['Only first','Standard usage','All small','All capital'], 
                           default='Unidentified ')
print (df)
   Id             Name        Category
0   1     Donald trump      Only first
1   2     Barack Obama  Standard usage
2   3  Hillary ClintoN   Unidentified 
3   4       BILL GATES     All capital
4   5       jeff bezoz       All small
5   6  Mark Zuckerberg  Standard usage
```

---

Idea by @Jon Clements, thank you:

```
m1 = df['Name'].str[1:].str.islower() & df['Name'].str[0].str.isupper()
df1 = df.Name.agg([str.istitle, str.islower, str.isupper])

df['Category'] = np.select(
    [m1, *df1.values.T], 
    ['Only first','Standard usage','All small','All capital'], 
    default='Unidentified '
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, there's very helpful

Comment: @NabihBawazir - First time used this functions, very nice ones ;)

Comment: How you find this function?

Comment: I have a script for extract all pandas function for easy copy for SO answers, so some time ago I notice this functions whech check this list. ;)

Comment: Another way for find them is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary)

Comment: You could possibly make use of `df.Name.agg([str.istitle, str.islower, str.isupper])` here - and if you wanted - throw in a `re.compile('...').match` to get the `m1` as well...

Comment: @jezrael you can also get away without explicit assignments for m2, m3, and m4, and do `np.select([m1, *df1.values.T], ...)`

Comment: @JonClements - Interesting, I used this very rare ;), thank you

Comment: Side note: I know the `pd.Series.str` methods are v convenient, but worth mentioning that you can normally see a factor improvement by converting to list comprehensions, e.g. `[i.islower() for i in df['Name'].values]`.

Comment: @jezrael it's probably a matter of preference vs PEP8 - but you also get more screen space (and imho more readability) by doing styling something like https://gist.github.com/puppystack/b7a276e1f874182e80ea5547e2fab317

Answer (score 2):

You might need to modify the function as per your requirement. But this would give you a rough idea to do it using the python built-in functions.
You can use something like this.

```
name_list = ['Donald trump','Barack Obama','Hillary Clinton','BILL GATES','jeff bezoz','Mark Zuckerberg']

for name in name_list:
    if name.isupper():
        print(name, 'All capital')
    elif name.islower():
        print(name, 'All small')
    elif name.istitle():
        print(name, 'Standard usage')
    elif (name[0].isupper() and name[1:].islower()):
        print(name, 'Only first')
    else:
        print(name, 'Unidentified')
```